# Why does 'valueAsNumber' return NaN as a value?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

In the code below, I am trying to call `valueAsNumber` but I just get a NaN returned. When I use `parseInt` I get the result I expect. Why Is this?

```
<html>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
<head>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
<title>JavaScript: Demo 1</title>                                                                                                                                                                          
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">                                                                                                                                                   
</head>                                                                                                                                                                                                    

<body>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
<div id="numbers">                                                                                                                                                                                         
  <div id="inputs">                                                                                                                                                                                        
    <form name="inputForm">                                                                                                                                                                                
    <div class="prompt">Number 1: <input name="number1" type="text"></div>                                                                                                                                 
    <div class="prompt">Number 2: <input name="number2" type="text"></div>                                                                                                                                 
    </form>                                                                                                                                                                                                
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  <div id="result">                                                                                                                                                                                        
    <div class="prompt">RESULT: <span id="operation_result">&nbsp;</span></div>                                                                                                                            
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                   
</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                     
<div id="operations">                                                                                                                                                                                      
<p><a id="add_link" href="#" onClick="add(this)">ADD</a></p>                                                                                                                                               
</div>                                                                                                                                                                                                     

<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                                                            
  function add(linkElement){                                                                                                                                                                               
  // var value1 = parseInt(document.inputForm.number1.value);
  // var value2 = parseInt(document.inputForm.number2.value);

  var value1 = document.inputForm.number1.valueAsNumber;
  var value2 = document.inputForm.number2.valueAsNumber;                                                                                                                                              
    var result = value1 + value1;                                                                                                                                                                          

    document.getElementById('operation_result').innerHTML = result;                                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                        
</script>                                                                                                                                                                                                  

</body>                                                                                                                                                                                                    
</html>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your expectations are reasonable considering the property name, but reading actual [specs/documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-valueasnumber):

> The valueAsNumber IDL attribute represents the value of the element,
> interpreted as a number.
>
> On getting, if the valueAsNumber attribute does not apply, as defined
> for the input element's type attribute's current state, then return a
> Not-a-Number (NaN) value.

[Here's a table](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#input-type-attr-summary) that list's `type`s that apply to `valueAsNumber`. These are:

- Date and Time (`datetime`) (Note this `type=""` is now obsolete in HTML LS)
- Date (`date`)
- Month (`month`)
- Week (`week`)
- Time (`time`)
- Local Date and Time (`datetime-local`)
- Number (`number`)
- Range (`range`)

**Observe that `type="text"` is conspicuously absent from the above list**, therefore `textInput.valueAsNumber` will always return `NaN` even when `isNaN( parseInt( textInput.value, 10 ) ) === false`.

Comment: ie still returning NaN.
tried  type=number in windows 10.

Comment: Everything's OK, just type: inp_el.type='number'; inp_el.value='12' or 12 and you'll see valueAsNumber=12

Answer (score 9):

You have to set the `type` of your `input` to `number`:

```
<input name="number1" type="number">
```

Also, if the value is empty or non-numeric, it'll return `NaN`.

Comment: Watch out, this still doesn't work in edge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251265/on-an-inputtype-number-edge-always-returns-nan-for-valueasnumber

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with a cast:

```js
 var nOP = Number(document.getElementById("hidNED").value);
```

In my case only possible contents of hidNED were 0, 1, 2, 3.
I am pretty new to javascript and was not aware of valueAsNumber but may well have tried it if I had been.