# On an input[type='number'] Edge always returns `NaN` for `valueAsNumber`

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-edge

The following works fine in Chrome and Firefox, however in Edge it will alert `NaN` no matter the input

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
 alert(document.querySelector('input').valueAsNumber);
});
```

```html
<input type='number' value='34'>
<button>
  Alert number
</button>
```

Now, I am *not* asking how to fix this (using `parseFloat(el.value)` does that trick), I am asking however what Edge did implement `valueAsNumber` for then if the most basic function doesn't seem to work. As in, how is one supposed to use this property **according to Edge**.

Comment: what's your Edge version?   `Edge 13` support `valueAsNumber()`

Comment: @Cattla Ehm, I just said that it's returning `NaN`, so obviously it's supported (unsupported properties are undefined ;-) ). Additionally I think you're talking about the EdgeHTML version, not the Edge version. Either way: Edge 25 and EdgeHTML 13

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft Edge is having broken behavior on `valueAsNumber`. This is reported as bug [#669685](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/669685/). In addition, setting `valueAsNumber` yields an InvalidStateException.

This is fixed in Microsoft Edge 17682, currently available in an Windows Insider build.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why Edge doesn't support `valueAsNumber` on `type="number"`, but it does support it on range, week, month, and date:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    alert(e.target.previousElementSibling.valueAsNumber);
  }
});
```

```html
<p><input type="range" value="15">          <button>Alert number</button></p>
<p><input type="week"  value="2015-W50">    <button>Alert number</button></p>
<p><input type="month" value="2015-12">     <button>Alert number</button></p>
<p><input type="date"  value="2015-12-12">  <button>Alert number</button></p>
```

Comment: This makes so little sense that it's amazing.