# Can you use input type "number" for arbitrary precision decimals?

Tags: javascript, html, input, precision

I would like to be able to handle numbers from e-18 (0.000000000000000001) to e4 (10,000) and do arithmetic on these inputs without rounding errors. So I cannot use the 64-bit double precision number native to JavaScript as it only has a safe range of 9e15 and I need a range of 1e22.

Can I use the HTML input type `number` for this in combination with the appropriate JavaScript, or should I use `text` instead?

Some code examples and npm libraries to help me solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked into `big.js`? https://www.npmjs.com/package/big.js

Comment: Yes, I found that and `decimal.js` which both looked up for the JS task. And from KostasX' answer, I think I should be able to parse the `value` property to a datatype from one of these libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The HTML input elements, always return a String represantation of the entered [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

2) For handling big numbers safely, you can either use the [ES6 BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) or if you want full cross-browser support, you can use a library such as [big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/wiki), [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/wiki) or [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/wiki), depending on your needs.

3) You might also want to take a look at the [valueAsNumber](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) property of the HTML input element (type=number). Beware of [support issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251265/on-an-inputtype-number-edge-always-returns-nan-for-valueasnumber#answer-46494927) for this one.

Bottom line: You will always get the value entered in the input field as a String data type via the **value** property, and you will have to parse it either natively or using a JS library as mention above.

---

Useful links about numbers and dealing with them in JavaScript:

- [Working with large integers in JavaScript](https://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html)
- [How numbers are encoded in JavaScript](https://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html)
- [When Your Code Does a Number on You: Navigating Numbers in JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dghqvjpdE5I) *(YouTube video)*

Comment: So if I am using input type `number`, I can just use its `e.target.value` as a string in an `onChange` JS function and not have to worry that the value is cast to a double?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge As long as you parse the string value using one of the libraries mentioned, you should be OK. Be sure to test a couple of values, just to make sure that everything works as intended.