# Invalid Date when using .valueAsNumber from inputs

Tags: javascript, html, date

```js
var yearInput = document.getElementById('year');
var monthInput = document.getElementById('month');
var dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
var start = new Date(yearInput.valueAsNumber, monthInput.valueAsNumber - 1, dateInput.valueAsNumber);
var end = new Date(2018, 02 - 1, 14);
var show = function(){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = start;}
var coded = function(){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = end;}
```

```html
<h2>Date Calc</h2>
<br>
Year
<input id = "year" type = number >
<br>
Month
<input id = "month" type = number >
<br>
Date
<input id = "date" type = number >
<br>
<button onclick="show();">Inputs</button>
<button onclick="coded();">Coded Date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

When trying to create a new date from input (type = number) given in HTML,

```
var yearInput = document.getElementById('year');
var monthInput = document.getElementById('month');
var dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
```

I use these variables as the parameters for creating a new date

```
var start = new Date(yearInput.valueAsNumber, monthInput.valueAsNumber - 1, dateInput.valueAsNumber);
```

'Invalid Date' is returned.

However, using numbers works just fine.

```
var end = new Date(2018, 02 - 1, 14);
```

Returns Wed Feb 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

The only thing changing would be the parameters. How are they different from each other?

Comment: Did you set `type="number"` on your `<input>`? If not, `.valueAsNumber` returns `NaN` (at least in chrome, I don't see that documented https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: There are a lot of answers here about valueAsNumber returning `NaN` or `undefined`. Please browse SO before posting.

Comment: The input type is set equal to number.

I'm also not getting `NaN` or `undefined`. I'm getting `Invalid Date`. I have not found any other helpful answers on the site yet. I don't understand how using the valueAsNumber doesn't work but actual numbers in the code does. I've run the debugger and it seems that the values are numbers, so I don't see how it should be any different.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction of the error on SO with the html/css/js snippet editor?

Comment: I've added the snippet with a button for each scenario.

Comment: Update: Ok, so doing some more experimenting has shed some light on things. When I set a variable equal to the `.valueAsNumber` the variable does come up as `NaN` in the debugger. So that probably explains the `Invalid Date` but why? If I do this, `var year = yearInput.valueAsNumber;` why is `year` not a number?

Comment: [With the update that `.valueAsNumber` was not returning a number (though that was not apparent), I did find another post questioning why this occurs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062069/why-does-valueasnumber-return-nan-as-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript runs first and saves the value to the variable `start` before any of the input values have been changed.

Each time you click the **inputs** button it uses the original value of `start` that has been saved when the JavaScript first ran.

You need to update so that each click of **Inputs** gets the current value of **day**, **month**, **year**, then calculate a new version of `start`, then update the HTML.

```js
var end = new Date(2018, 02 - 1, 14);
var show = function(){
  var yearInput = document.getElementById('year');
  var monthInput = document.getElementById('month');
  var dateInput = document.getElementById('date');
  var start = new Date(yearInput.valueAsNumber, monthInput.valueAsNumber - 1, dateInput.valueAsNumber);  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = start;
}
var coded = function(){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = end;}
```

```html
<h2>Date Calc</h2>
<br>
Year
<input id = "year" type = number >
<br>
Month
<input id = "month" type = number >
<br>
Date
<input id = "date" type = number >
<br>
<button onclick="show();">Inputs</button>
<button onclick="coded();">Coded Date</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```