# What is the default type of input field value when particularly specified to type="number"?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using reactJs with React hooks and context Api, In the normal html form, I'm having to input tags with type is text, When i trying to know what type of values we are getting in with "typeOf" function in javascript. I got string type when i'm entering string value, but when i enter a number it is showing undefined.

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
const [movies , setMovie] = useContext(MovieContext) 

const updateName = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value)
}

const updatePrice = (e) => {
    setPrice(e.target.price);
}

const addMovie = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMovie(prevMovies => {
       return [...prevMovies, { name: name, price: price }]
    })
    console.log(typeof(price)) //getting undefined
    console.log(typeof(name)) //getting string 
}

return ( 
    <div>
       <form onSubmit={addMovie}>
           <input type="text"  name="name" value={name} onChange={ updateName }/>
           <input type="text"  name="price" value={price} onChange={ updatePrice } />
           <button>Submit</button>
       </form>
    </div>
 );
```

Comment: Did you mean `<input type="number"  name="price"`?

Comment: input values are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the value to number in order to get the value as a number as you don't have `price` attribute that store the value.

```
setPrice(Number(e.target.value));
```

Also, you can change the type of the input to number as well

Comment: I want that price value to be string, because in the useState('') I defined it to be empty string that treats any updated value to be string only. But when I log with typeof(price) function in JavaScript...it is showing undefined.

Comment: Instead of `e.target.price` use `e.target.value`

Comment: Oh No, that's my mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML has exactly one data type: Text (string).**

All values extracted from HTML elements are strings. If you need a value to be treated differently, it will be up to your JavaScript to convert the type. For numeric data, there are several ways, but perhaps the simplest is to prepend an arithmetic operator, [like `+`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-unary-operators-simple-and-useful#toc-unary-plus-) to the value.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("blur", function(){
  console.log("Data is: " + typeof input.value);
  console.log("Converted type is: " + typeof +input.value);
});
```

```html
Enter a number and press TAB: <input type="number">
```

If your data begins with a number but also has non-numeric characters following it, then [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) will extract the number and stop when non-numeric values are found:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("blur", function(){
  console.log("Data is: " + typeof input.value);
  // It's a best-practice to always specify the second argument for parseInt()
  // to ensure the correct conversion.
  console.log("Converted type is: " + typeof parseInt(input.value, 10));
});
```

```html
Enter a number and press TAB: <input type="number">
```

Comment: It's worth adding that there is the [`HTMLInputElement.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) property as well, though it has been noted as [unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062069/why-does-valueasnumber-return-nan-as-a-value) here on SO.

Comment: @DavidThomas There's also `Number()` which I didn't cover as I feel that `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()`, and the unary `+` do the trick.

Comment: I want that price value to be string, because in the useState('') I defined it to be empty string that treats any updated value to be string only. But when I log with typeof(price) function in JavaScript...it is showing undefined.