# Greater than something bug in Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting a weird bug where in my game, where you enter a guess that is greater than the maxNum like 8 as the guess and the maxNum entered is 10. The game is supposedly think 8 is greater than 10. The issue with the code is coming from the **checkGuess** function. I have no idea if it is cause I am using global variables.

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If the problem is with a single function, take the function out and either add a bit more code or modify it so it still runs and demonstrates the issue without making people sift through a bunch of unrelated code.

Comment: I haven't looked all that closely at your code, but when you take user input you generally receive a _string_, so you may be comparing the string "8" to the number 10, throwing the comparison off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you get from input `value` is always a String (text). In order to get a proper number, please use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) if you expect integers, or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat) for floating point numbers.

For your specific case, the code could look like this:

```
maxNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('maxGuessRange').value, 10);
```

Please be aware to always set the number base parameter explicitly (`10` in this example means decimal) because the default behavior, when no parameter is given, is unsafe and can be easily confused with octal and other number systems.

The bug comes from the code like this, which results in `true` when strings are compared instead of numbers:

```
'10' < '8'
```

Please always parse user input to proper number types to avoid unexpected coercions.

Comment: Or use `.valueAsNumber`

Comment: @evolutionxbox That is great learning for me today, thanks! Just a note, please be aware this won't work for inputs that do not set explicitly the type to `number`.

    temp1 = <input type=​"text">​
    temp1.valueAsNumber
    NaN
    
    temp2 = <input type=​"number">​
    temp2.valueAsNumber
    123

Comment: There are more input types that support `valueAsNumber` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18062487/1384679