# Why the function areaRettangolo return Nan?

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't the function `areaRettangolo` return a number?
I want to calculate the area of a rectangle using a function called `areaRettangolo` but it returns `Nan`

```js
let base = document.getElementById('base');
let altezza = document.getElementById('altezza');
let bottone = document.querySelector('button');
let testo = document.querySelector('h1');
let area = 0;

function areaRettangolo(a, b) {
  let c = 0;
  c = a * b;
  return c;
}
bottone.addEventListener('click', () => {
  area = areaRettangolo(base, altezza);
  console.log(area);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="base" placeholder="inserisci la base del rettangolo"><br><br>
<input type="number" id="altezza" placeholder="inserisci l'altezza del rettangolo"><br><br>
<button>Calcola l'area del rettangolo</button>
<h1>-</h1>
```

Comment: You're passing the whole input element object to your function, not the numeric value that it currently holds. See [`.value` or `.valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `base` and `altezza` are [HTMLElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) and not the numbers you are expecting. To get the inserted numbers you need to send `input.value` to the function instead.

The inputs `base` and `altezza` are of type `number` so `input.valueAsNumber` is a better alternative, as it returns the values as numbers instead of strings.

Be carrefull, `input.valueAsNumber` works only for some input types as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062069/why-does-valueasnumber-return-nan-as-a-value).

```js
let base = document.getElementById('base');
let altezza = document.getElementById('altezza');
let bottone = document.querySelector('button');
let testo = document.querySelector('h1');

function areaRettangolo(a, b) {
  // you can pass the value directly to the variable
  let c =  a * b;
  return c;
}
bottone.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // the area variable is not used out of this function so you dont need to create it on the global scope
  let area = areaRettangolo(base.valueAsNumber, altezza.valueAsNumber); // here, use the `.valueAsNumber` on the imput elements
  testo.innerHTML = "La superficie è: " + area;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="base" placeholder="inserisci la base del rettangolo"><br><br>
<input type="number" id="altezza" placeholder="inserisci l'altezza del rettangolo"><br><br>
<button>Calcola l'area del rettangolo</button>
<h1>-</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) (**N**ot **a** **N**umber) because when you execute `c = a * b;` JavaScript expects `a` and `b` to be numbers or types that can be converted to a number (for example, a numeric string `"123"` can be converted to the number `123`).

In your code `a` and `b` are both a [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) which cannot be converted to a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) automatically.

Use `.value` in conjunction with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get the current value of the element (use `parseInt` if you expect/allow only whole numbers, `parseFloat` otherwise):

```
area = areaRettangolo(parseFloat(base.value), parseFloat(altezza.value));
```

You don't need to change anything inside the `areaRettangolo` function.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ***.value*** after ***altezza*** and ***base***.
Becouse **document.getElementById** return a HTMLElement tag and you do'nt have
direct access to values them! (value)

```
let base = document.getElementById('base');
let altezza = document.getElementById('altezza');
let bottone = document.querySelector('button');
let testo = document.querySelector('h1');
let area = 0;

function areaRettangolo(a, b) {
  let c = 0;
  c = a * b;
  return c;
}
bottone.addEventListener('click', () => {
// You can use .valueAsNumber instead of .value becouse your innput value is allways number.
  area = areaRettangolo(base.value, altezza.value);
  console.log(area);
});
```

Htmls Code :

```
<input type="number" id="base" placeholder="inserisci la base del rettangolo"><br><br>
<input type="number" id="altezza" placeholder="inserisci l'altezza del rettangolo"><br><br>
<button>Calcola l'area del rettangolo</button>
<h1>-</h1>
```